# Measure height of listview items

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to measure the height of each item in a `ListView` before the rendering.

I added this method to my custom `ListView`

```
public void measureItemsHeight() {
    mItemCount = getAdapter().getCount();

    if(mItemOffsetY == null){
        mItemOffsetY = new int[mItemCount];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < mItemCount; ++i){
        View view  = getAdapter().getView(i, null, this);  
        view.measure(0, 0);  
        mItemHeight[i] = view.getMeasuredHeight();
    }
}
```

Then, inside my activity's `onCreate()`:

```
mListView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            mListView.measureItemsHeight();
        }
    }
);
```

The values i get are different than the ones reported by `getHeight()`, eg `getMeasuredHeight()` returns 48, and the `getHeight()` returns 72.

The layout i use for the items is the `simple_list_item`

It looks to me this like a hdpi and xhdpi problem, is there a way to fix this? The device I use to debug is the Samsung SGS2, maybe that is the problem.

Comment: Can you attach `simple_list_item.xml`? Also, can you give some *context*, explaining why you want to measure the height of all the possible children?

Comment: well i needed to get the height of my items to make a own ScrollY te get how much pixels i have scrolled in the listview because you can't track that normally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to use custom list,Make separate layout for list row.
Assign following property to that views layout:`android:layout_height=wrap_content`. 
Thats it.
Good Luck!